# Unmoderated Usability Study

Tags: usability-testing

I am a UX/UI design student and I want to do unmoderated usability studies but I can't find any platform to do it properly.

I started to build my whole usability test on Maze, which was perfect for me until I found out I can only have 7 boards in my Usability test and I need more.
Upgrading is $33/month if I pay monthly which is not bad, but when I wanted to check out, the price has doubled because you NEED to pay for two people(?)

I checked most of the usability testing tools (like UserZoom, Lookback, MarvelApp, UxCam, UsabilityHub, etc.) but the only way to sign up for most of them is with a company, and I need a company email address and/or it's $500/month.

I am a student. I am broke. I just want to do a proper unmoderated usability study. I know I can do it with simple screen and audio recordings and just send them the Figma link but... still.

Is there a proper tool to do unmoderated usability testing as an individual?
I need to make multiple testings since I'm working on case studies to be able to build a portfolio, and get a job etc. etc.

Comment: Hi Lisa, just curious - why is unmoderated a requirement for your study? Would doing in-person studies with laptops and phones not work for what you're testing?

Comment: Hi Lisa, as the question stands it is more about tools rather than a specific UX design problem. If this is the case, I would recommend that this question be migrated to Software Recommendation StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the issue of recording the audio and screen, or screen capture only. As a senior I wouldn't hold it against any designers. These are expensive tools and offer niche benefits. The one my company subscribes to is a stepper that integrates into the browser so really it's just limiting the questions displayed one at a time, and the study auto closes once it hits it's participant limit, and prints a report when it's done.

**I'd be more interested to see your design artifacts**: writing quality for the script, what questions did you ask?, how well are the questions are executed (lots of ways to bias this)?, how did you screen the participants?, and how you interpret and communicate the results.